# How to test for a system library prerequisite in Build.PL

Tags: perl, perl-module

Given that I'm using Module::Build to build my perl module, I'd like to test for specific system library prerequisites in my Build.PL and exit with an error if they are not found. This seems like the best way to ensure that the necessary prerequisites will be met when the compiler is called. I could just let the compilation fail when it links, but I think detecting prior to building is better. It's probably a matter of just searching the same lib directories that the build system will use when compiling, but I'm hoping there is some functionality in Module::Build that could help figure this out.

To be specific, in my case I want to verify that libicu is installed and available in the libpath used by the compiler.

Comment: This is essentially trying to do what a standard `./configure` does for, say, C programs, right? IIRC, `configure` creates stub C programs that include the libraries in question, then compiles (and possibly executes) them, checking the status when they're done. That sounds like what you could try, but it's a little on the complicated side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Devel::CheckLib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aCheckLib).  (There's also [ExtUtils::PkgConfig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aPkgConfig) for libraries that use [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) to report configuration details.)

BTW, the [standard way](http://wiki.cpantesters.org/wiki/CPANAuthorNotes) for Build.PL to report that a non-Perl-module prerequisite is not available is for it to print a message explaining what's missing and then `exit 0` *without* calling `create_build_script`.  Devel::CheckLib provides a `check_lib_or_exit` function for doing that.

Comment: CheckLib looks promising - I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach is to use [ExtUtils::PkgConfig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aPkgConfig) if it's a `pkg-config` based library, or [ExtUtils::CChecker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aCChecker) to check for more difficult things, such as older libraries that don't use `pkg-config`, or more subtle OS features and abilities.